# Сортировка массива объектов JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив объектов, нужно отсортировать его по значению поля, расположив элементы с одинаковым значением рядом друг с другом. 
Пример:

```
var arr1 = [
   {str:'strA'},
   {str:'bStr'},
   {str:'Cstr'},
   {str:'strA'},
   {str:'bstr'};
]; //исходный массив

var arr1 = [
   {str:'strA'},
   {str:'strA'},
   {str:'bStr'},
   {str:'bstr'},
   {str:'Cstr'};
]; //исходный массив
```

В "вооружении" имеются `knockout.js` и `underscore.js`.

Comment: У Вас странная последовательность: почему 9 раньше 3?

Comment: это пример. интересует не возрастающая последовательность цифр, а сортировка таким образом, чтобы одинаковые значения оказались рядом в массиве.

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет метод массивов [sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

```
arr = [
  {str: 1},
  {str: 2},
  {str: 3},
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.str > b.str });
```

Если нужно оставить исходный массив несортированным, то для копирования можно воспользоваться методом [slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

```
arr2 = arr1.slice()
```

Comment: My bad. параметр по которому сортируется: строка.

Comment: Исправил ответ под ваш новый пример.